# VSCode won't open (bus error)

Tags: 18.04, crash, visual-studio-code

I was working as usual but out of nowhere vscode crashed with a code '135' I tried reopen it but keeps showing the error window, then I reset my computer and tried to opden vscode but it just blinks for a while and disappear it wont open. I tried using `code --version` but it returned `Bus error (core dumped)` also tried `code --verbose` with same result. Any idea on how to reset VSCode or what to do in this case?

I use Ubuntu 18.04 LTS